# Remove members of given list, which appear after a sublist

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to remove of all members of a list appearing after a sublist [z,z,z] in Prolog.
f.ex `removeafterZZZ([a,b,c,z,z,z,a], X) -> X = [a,b,c,z,z,z].`

I have the methods **sublist** and **join** given.

```
    % first argument is a sublist of the second argument
    sublist(Sublist, List):-
       join(_List1, List2, List),
       join(Sublist,_List3, List2).


    % we get the list in third argument by joining lists from first two arguments
    join([], L, L).
    join([Head | Tail1], List2, [Head | Tail3]):-
    join(Tail1, List2, Tail3).
```

So I've been thinking of 3 possible input "options":

1) []

2) something like [a,b,c], [a,b,c,z,z] , where the output automatically would be == input

3) something like [a,b,c,z,z,z,a]

So i thought of 3 Rules:

```
removeafterZZZ([],[]).   %for empty lists
removeafterZZZ(List,X) :=                   %for lists with no [z,z,z] sublist
       not ( sublist ( [z,z,z], List)) , 
       X = List.

removeafterZZZ([H|T], X) :=           %for lists with sublist [z,z,z]
       join(H, X, X),                 %join the head of list with X
       removeafterZZZ(T, X).          %call function again with tail
```

So that obviously doesn't work this way, how do i know if i already wrote z,z,z into the output list? Should I use a counter? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed to use append (it's a standard list predicate supplied with prolog), here's a generic method to remove a suffix --

```
% removeAfterSuff(Original List, Suffix To Remove, Result)
removeAfterSuff(X, [], X) :- !.
removeAfterSuff(X, Y, X) :- \+ sublist(Y,X).
removeAfterSuff(X, Y, Z) :- append(A, B, X), append(Y, _, B), append(A,Y,Z).
```

It uses a cut, so it's a bit ugly, but otherwise predicate 2 will give a bunch of results if you pass in [] (yeah yeah, red cut, whatever).

Here's how it works, if the suffix is NOT a member of the list, option 2 activates and X and Z are equal. Otherwise it says "there exist two lists, A and B that can make my original list. This second list, B, starts with my suffix, and then contains everything (and I don't care what that stuff is). Since I know that A is everything before the suffix, then my result is A concatenated with Y."

Note that this will give you multiple results for a list like

```
[a,b,z,z,z,a,b,z,z,z]
```

Edit to add: You can remove the first line if you're okay with an empty list returning results like

```
removeAfterSuff([a,b,c], [], Z).
Z = []
Z = [a]
Z = [a,b]
Z = [a,b,c]
```

Comment: He is allowed to use append, except he called it `join` in the OP.

Comment: Ah, so it is. I thought maybe join was secretly append, but didn't look at it thoroughly enough to be sure.

Comment: thank you very much for that nice explanation! that does indeed solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to worry about three cases (so three rules...)

1. Empty list `[]`
2. List starting with `[z,z,z]`
3. Non-empty list that doesn't start with `[z,z,z]`

Think of how you would solve this in a traditional language - you walk the list until it ends or you find a `[z,z,z]` pattern in the middle.

Comment: Thx for your answer! So case 1) Empty List: `removeafterZZZ([],[]).   %for empty lists` is my rule correct? You just get an empty list back.

For the other cases. In traditional languages I would have a counter i=0 and +1 for every z and if z=3 ignore the rest of the list.
That would solve Case 2)3)

But how do I solve this in prolog? ;)

Comment: @thenet, then your code would be wrong, I think. For `[z, a, z, z, x]` it would return `[z, a, z, z]`, even though it doesn't contain `[z, z, z]`.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is homework a complete response has already been given so...

```
remove_after([], _, []).
remove_after([H|L], P, O) :-
        (   append(P, _, [H|L])
        ->  O = P
        ;   O = [H|O1],
            remove_after(L, P, O1) ).
```